# Recursive CTE in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm trying to learn how to use common table expressions as introduced in SQL 1999 to solve a generic bill of materials problem.  I assume given the following tables:

```
create table part(id int, name string, price int)
create table assembly(part_id int, subpart_id int, quantity int)
```

A row in the assembly table represents the fact that a part contains several instances of a subpart, which may in turn have its own subparts, and so on.  The assembly table represents a structure, a tree, with a given part_id as its root.

I'd like to compute the total number of occurrences of each part in the structure.

Here is my attempt using common table expressions:

```
WITH RECURSIVE bom(part_id, component_id, total) AS
    (SELECT id, id, 1 FROM part 
        UNION
     SELECT assembly.part_id, bom.component_id, sum(assembly.quantity * bom.total)
     FROM assembly, bom
     WHERE assembly.subpart_id = bom.part_id
     GROUP BY assembly.part_id, bom.component_id)
SELECT component_id, total FROM bom WHERE part_id = root;
```

Under SQLite 3.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.5, I get the following error message:
Error: near line 78: recursive aggregate queries not supported

So, is this an SQLite restriction, or is it an SQL standard restriction?

In either case, can anyone advise me how to rewrite this solution to accumulate more information in the common table expression and then perform the aggregate in the query that uses the resulting table?

Many thanks,
Rodney

Comment: Your example runs for me with sqlite3.

Comment: Postgres also refuses to do this. But I think your sum() is wrong in the first place. I think what you want is a simple bom.total + assembly.quantity (so adding up all quantity values in the tree). Plus I think it would be more efficient if you selected the root node directly inside the CTE: `from part where id = root`

Comment: I may not have described the problem clearly enough.  If there are 4 occurrences of a wheel in a car, and 5 occurrences of a nut in a wheel, then there should be 20 occurrences of a nut in a car.  So you need to multiply quantity by total.  Then you need to sum over all intermediate parts, e.g., wheels and other subparts that contain nuts.

Comment: In that case you need to do the aggregation in the outer query.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the problem can be solved in that way to overcome the apparent lack of support for recursive aggregate queries.

Comment: Just for info: SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 and Firebird also refuse to use an aggregate function in the recursive part. Seems to be a general restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to solve the problem by moving the aggregation to the outer query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE bom(part_id, component_id, total) AS
    (SELECT id, id, 1 FROM part 
        UNION ALL
     SELECT assembly.part_id, bom.component_id, assembly.quantity * bom.total
     FROM assembly, bom
     WHERE assembly.subpart_id = bom.part_id)
SELECT component_id, SUM(total) FROM bom 
WHERE part_id = root
GROUP BY component_id;
```

This solution requires more space and potentially more time than the initial attempt.